# Non-strict inequalities are preserved by limits

Tags: calculus

Could you please explain (with examples) what the following idea means?

> Non-strict inequalities are preserved by limits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author simply means the following:

> Let $(a_{n})_{n}$ and $(b_{n})_{n}$ be sequences converging to $a$ and $b$, respectively, and satisfying $a_{n}\geq b_{n}$ for all $n$. Then, $a\geq b$.

Here's an example: $1/n > 0$ for each $n$, and hence the limit $a=0$ of the sequence $(1/n)_n$ also satisfies $a \geq 0$. Note, however, that $a$ does not satisfy $a > 0$. Hence, the term "non-strict" is important here.

Comment: Thank you for a perfectly clear reply!

Comment: @Konstantin: no problem. All the best.